# matplotlib figure still internally uses screen size after using figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize

I'm using `plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))` to adjust the size and aspect ratio of the window that is generated when showing a plot. 
However, my tick annotations on the vertical axis are very long so that they disappear from the window. But, lo and behold, they *do* fit on my screen if I then manually adjust the window size to my screen size.

It thus seems that although you can manually modify the window size using the `figsize` option, `matplotlib` still generates the figure as if you were going to use it in a maximized window. How can I change the figure size that is used internally? (What should I do to make `matplotlib` resize the image so it actually fits in the window I have defined?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a misconception. Matplotlib uses exactly one figure size, which is the one given by `figsize`. There is no such thing as internal or external figure size.

When changing the window's size, you change the figure size. The result you get is the same whether you create a figure with `figsize=(4,4)` and later scale it up with your mouse on the screen, or whether you directly use a figure size of e.g. `(20,8)`.

It might be that in reality you want to make the contents of the figure, fit inside the figure itself.
This can be done using several mechanisms, e.g. [`plt.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#move-the-edge-of-an-axes-to-make-room-for-tick-labels) or [`plt.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

Comment: thanks, the `plt.tight_layout()` with `pad=0` option gave me some extra room to work with :-)